# How to translate language json files?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm using ngx-translate to localizing the app developed by angular. Since there are more than 20 languages ​​that need to be translated, I need a tool that can translate the language json files.

I found a [website](https://www.logisticinfotech.com/translate-language-files-online-json/) that helps，but it takes a long time, and sometimes I can’t receive emails with translation results.

So Is there a tool that can parse the json file and tranlate it please.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "attranslate" is a modern tool that solves the problem: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate It is full open-source and can be used for free

Comment: Hi @Crashalot, eventually I have not found a solution

Comment: @moqiyuanshi does https://hotpot.ai/file-translator solve the problem? if not, we could make changes so it become a solution for your json translation problem.

Comment: @Crashalot It's a great tool, it would be better if there is a free solution ^^

Comment: @Crashalot I'm good, thanks. I had quitted my job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [simpleen.io](https://simpleen.io) does exactly that.

It supports the JSON format including different depths. It currently supports a dozen languages (based on DeepL). It also supports the default interpolation of variables in ngx-translate, which are marked as {{variableName}}.

Basically you signup, configure a translator and then you can use it directly via copy&pasting your JSON structure. It takes probably 1-3 seconds, then you receive your result.

It is currently in beta, but will support more languages when other translation services are implemented.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of the service, so if you have any questions or feedback, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Denis, your service is really nice, it's quick. just some small feedback, it seems that there is not  enough options (language), and It is not very convenient to set the target language in advance.
Anyway, I love the your app. Hope it can become more famous. ^^

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I really appreciate it. More languages will come as soon as we translate with additional language providers, i.e. google translate. We will improve the usability in coming releases

Comment: @Denis nice work bro. Easy to use and really saved my time and trouble

Comment: Free and easiest way is https://translate.i18next.com/